# Is it possible to push python files to nexus repository

Tags: python, maven, nexus

I have a python project that contains few `.py` files and few `.xml` files. I would like to push my project to our local nexus repository using maven. How can I do that? This is what I'm doing but it is not pushing all the files.

```
  mvn -q deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=main.py -Dfiles=file1.py,file2.py,file3.py 
      -Dtypes=py,py,py -Dclassifiers=src,src,src -DrepositoryId=nexus 
      -Durl="https://nexus.local.com/content/repositories/myproject" 
       -DgroupId=com.company -DartifactId=myproject -Dversion=1.0.0
```

When I execute the above, I can only see files `myproject-1.0.0.py`  and `myproject-1.0.0-src.py`. Instead, what I would prefer to see is `main.py` `file1.py` `file2.py` `file3.py`

Is this possible to do using maven and nexus for python projects?

Comment: When you use Maven repositories your files will get Maven naming conventions.  Why not use PyPi repositories?  http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/pypi.html

Comment: Do I need to convert my package as a PyPi repository in order to do that?

Comment: Also I'm doing this on a local Nexus server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use a Maven repository, I would suggest you zip the files using maven-assembly-plugin. If you need them in another project, you can unpack them with `dependency:unpack`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a PyPi repository instead for this, unless there is some absolute need to have the files in the Maven repository. If using a PyPi repository is too onerous you could also just push the files using [curl to a Raw repository](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/raw.html#_uploading_files_to_hosted_raw_repositories)